# ASP MVC C# Cascading dropdown using single table

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, cascading

I have a single oracle table with 5 columns and I need to create 5 cascading dropdown lists on the MVC view page, using combination of Razor and jquery.   I got the first dropdown ok which comes from the Model passed on to the view.   Having trouble figuring out the 2nd dropdown and after.

Any sample code or examples would be appropriated

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved.  I ended up using jquery+ajax to make cascaded calls to the controller with each call passing the previous dropdown boxes values and returning a selectList of items from the DB.

Thanks